# VSCode: Add new activity bar entries & custom "pages"

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'd like to add new activity bar entries and create a custom "page" when developing an extension. Is that even possible?

My idea is create a database manager like Sequel Pro inside VSCode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

v.1.23 added the ability for extension authors to add icons to the activity bar.

[custom activity bar views](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23#_custom-activity-bar-views)

[extension code for contributing to the activity bar](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_23#_contributions-to-the-activity-bar)

Answer (score 0):

This concrete extension implements a custom Activity Bar.

As far as I know, you can put only a treeview there:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azureappservice