# How to modify VSCode Activity Bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm customizing VSCode and I need to modify Activity Bar, removing some icon and add one more icon to open extension which is now triggered by keyboard shortcut.

Does anybody have idea how to modify VSCode source code to accomplish that?

Is there any document helping me understand the source code of VSCode?

Any clue will be highly appreciated!

Comment: You can hide the default icons in the activity bar by right-clicking and deselecting whichever you don't want to see (or bring back).

Comment: thanks Mark, yes, I could hide default icons by the way you pointed out, but i could still find it by right-clicking on activity bar and bring it back. My goal is to remove it permanently and add some new icons linking to extensions. This gotta be done by modifying VSCode source code. Any idea?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877862/vscode-add-new-activity-bar-entries-custom-pages/50164671#50164671 v.12 added this functionality but it has to be enabled by the extension author.

Answer (score 5):

You can right click on the activity bar and select which activity you wish to have in the activity bar.

[image]

Comment: I think I accidentally dragged my Search out of Activity Bar so it's now a Panel (near Problems/Output/Terminal...) and UI doesn't allow me to drag it back and neither the Search option is present anymore in the context menu. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't reproduce your scenario. Could you provide the step to reproduce?

Comment: @DaviLima check your setting "search.location": "sidebar",

Comment: Thank you, @Erik! Life is Good Again, now.