# How to reorder VSCode activity bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to be able to reorder icons in the VSCode activity bar… I know that we can hide/show some icons ([How to modify VSCode Activity Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47390242/how-to-modify-vscode-activity-bar)) but is it possible to reorder them?

I've installed the "Project Manager" extension and I'd like to have it at the top of my activity bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reorder them by **drag** and **drop** on **Activity Bar** 
Source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_activity-bar